# Does the investment term "flip" have an etymological connection to the word invert?

Tags: etymology

The Spanish term for "an investment" is "una inversión"; "to invest" is "invertir". "Invertir" can also be used for the physical act of inverting something or turning it over.

The term "to flip" in American English can refer to making a short-term investment, often in real estate. "To flip" can also mean "to turn something upside down; to invert".

Is there an etymological connection between these dramatically different (invest vs. turn upside down) but shared meanings of "to flip" and "invertir"?

Comment: “Flip” can also mean “turn over”. Flipping a coin or a mattress isn’t really “inverting” it. “Turn over” also has the sense of an abrupt change of state or ownership, which seems like a closer tie to “flip” in this sense than “invert” to me.

Comment: _Flip_ is not onomatopoeia. No sound is involved in its meaning; onomatopoeia refers only to a word that imitates a sound, like _snap_ or _crackle_ . You may be thinking of sound symbolism, in particular, the phonosemantic senses of [the assonance `FL-`](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/fl.pdf) and [the rime `-IP`](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/-ip.pdf).

Comment: Flipping an investment refers to the speed of the buy and sell, with its associated sound: Pop, plop, pow, flash, tap, whiz-bang, whoosh.

Comment: If you want to believe that, it's your language.

Comment: @ColleenV, I would argue that flipping a mattress IS the same as inverting it (invert: put upside down or in the opposite position, order, or arrangement). However, I think you are right that "flip" is used for this type of real estate transaction because of the rapid turnover of inventory.

Comment: @Josh My point is that there’s really no reason to choose “invert” over “turn over” or “upend”. It’s this sort of thing that causes folk etymologies. Humans love finding patterns in things, even when there isn’t a meaningful one. And if I told my husband I needed help inverting the mattress, he would probably have no idea what I was talking about ;)

Comment: I probably should have done some googling in Spanish. It appears the "vertir" root of invertir means to go in circles (dar vueltas), double back, or double (as in multiply) (http://etimologias.dechile.net/?invertir). As ColleenV suggests, the connection to the English flip is likely spurious.